# How to route url multiple php web pages in Docker

Tags: php, docker, kubernetes

How to Route multiple php web pages on Dockerfile

I have three webpages

```
1) Index.php
2) Submit.php
3) nav.php
```

both shares the same navigation bar

```
(nav.php)
```

all these php files are considered as separate micro services and  all three of them are separate Docker images . How can I include

```
<?php include("nav.php") ?>
```

in index.php as they are all in separate containerize Docker image and  want to Deploy the web app on Gcloud using kubernetes Engine . I had deployed index.php on gcloud using kubernetes engine but index.php and nav.php was both in the same container but I want to seperate them just to practice how can I Deploy multiple webpages on multiple containers and use them as a single website

Comment: Don't put the PHP files in the containers and use a bindmount to share a common location for all the files instead.

Comment: If one thing is referencing another thing’s files, they aren’t really “services” _per se_ and they need to be in the same container.  You should make sure they get `COPY` into the same image in a Dockerfile.